# UINavigationBar loses tint color when I show a new UIView

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have added a tint to the UINavigationBar via the following lines of code in the AppDelegate:

```
let navBar = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navBar.barTintColor = mainColor
```

[image: first view controller]

However when I go to a different view via a segue, I lose the color. View 2 isn't embedded in its own UINavigationController.

[image: View 2]

If I embed it in a nav controller it appears however if I go to View 3 from View 2, it too disappears.

I'm using 'Show' as the segue option.

Answer (score 0):

I had used an @IBAction action to go from View 2 to View 3. That's why I had to replace

```
navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

with the following:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

I learned this via - [Go back to previous view controller doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35814405/go-back-to-previous-view-controller-doesnt-work)